# Why can't I change flex items size?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, height, width

Here is my code

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

* {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header nav ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 3em;
  background-color: #783F27;
}

.naviga {
  border: solid medium;
  border-radius: 0.4em;
  margin: 0 0.5em;
  width: 10em;
  color: goldenrod;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Learning</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a class="naviga" href="">Menu</a></li>
        <li><a class="naviga" href="">News</a></li>
        <li><a class="naviga" href="">About</a></li>
        <li><a class="naviga" href="">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

The `<li>` elements display with a width of `min-content` (or `max-content` that is the same in this case) even if I specify `width: 10em`. The same thing happens if I specify the `height`. Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the width of *li* instead of *a* tag please see the example below

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Learning</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
* {
    box-sizing: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

header nav ul {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 3em;
    background-color: #783F27;
}
.naviga {
    color: goldenrod;
}
.liClass {
    border: solid goldenrod;
    border-radius: 0.4em;
    margin: 0 0.5em;
    width: 20em;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li class="liClass"><a class="naviga" href="">Menu</a></li>
      <li class="liClass"><a class="naviga" href="">News</a></li>
      <li class="liClass"><a class="naviga" href="">About</a></li>
      <li class="liClass"><a class="naviga" href="">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Oh I see, I meant to give the class `naviga` to the `li` elements but I gave it to the anchors inside them. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess, I haven't ran the code yet, but it looks like this may be the issue?

```
 html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
   }
   * {
    box-sizing: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
   }
```

You have box sizing defined for the entire document twice. Try removing one of these, I will test your code then get back to you with more detail.

I would suggest box-sizing: border-box; for * and remove it from the html {} element

Also, add the display property to the css for your navga like this and it works.

```
.naviga {
  display: flex;
    border: solid medium;
    border-radius: 0.4em;
    margin: 0 0.5em;
    width: 200px;
    color: goldenrod;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `flex` property sets the flexible length on flexible items.
`flex: 0 0 40%`

Comment: but in theory I'm not required to use `flex-basis`, I can use `width` right?

Comment: When `flex-direction` is row, `flex-basis` controls the width.